# Equivalent of “collocate” but for time rather than space

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that can be a drop-in replacement for *collocate*, but referring to things existing or occurring at the same time as opposed to at same place.

I've considered *cotemporate* but it sounds made-up.

Example usage:

> I will *collocate* the two meetings so that they start and finish at the same time

Comment: You could verb *coincident* if you enjoy incomprehensible corporate buzzwords, but *plan* or *schedule* fit in your blank nicely.

Comment: 'colocated' doesn't mean 'at the exact same location' but rather 'closely nearby'. Do you want a time that is exactly the same or just time that is nearby?

Comment: While "cotemporate" is indeed made up, "contemporize" is defined at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemporize as "to make contemporary".

Comment: I like **coordinate** here.

Comment: You're thinking too hard about this.  `I will schedule the two meetings for the same time.`  or... `I will schedule the meetings to run in parallel`

Comment: `I will [arrange] the two meetings so that they start and finish at the same time`. .. (post-Einstein, with time viewed as a dimension, *collocate* should already imply being located together in spacetime not just in space, shouldn't it?)

Comment: Most of these answers fill in the blank, but they don't answer the title, which IMO would need a phrase, lest it be misunderstood: *scheduled to coincide*. Also, *The meetings are scheduled to coincide.* would cut the sentence length in half. - But, *I will synchronize the meetings.* ? What are you, a swimmer, or is this a teleconference?

Comment: Not quite what this is about ... There is a term *bilocation* for the supposed ability of certain mystics to be in two different places at the same time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

***Synchronize*** will work for you.  It can be used transitively just like collocate.

> synchronize (verb) *trans.* To cause to be, or represent as,
>   synchronous; to assign the same date to; to bring together events,
>   etc. belonging to the same time. ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196396?redirectedFrom=synchronize#eid))

**Requested example usage:**

I will *synchronize* the two meetings so that they start and finish at the same time.

Comment: If you ignore the Latin/Greek difference, both words are incredibly similar: "Co(n)" (together) + "Locatus" (location) and "Syn" (together) + "Chronos" (time).

Comment: Actually, isn't adding "...so that they start and finish at the same time." redundant?  Couldn't you just say "I will *synchronize* the two meetings." to be more concise?

Comment: This is ideal for the asker's particular example, as synchronization applies not only to the start of the events but also their duration. If the two meetings started at the same time but ran different lengths, then you might say their start times are synchronized, but the meetings themselves are not.

Comment: Considering the etymological research given by Flater in the comment above, I would be interested in the reason for the downvote. Not that I am offended, but by definition and etymology, this word is an **exact** drag-and-drop replacement for collocate which is what the OP asked for.  If it was @Mazura's downvote, I'd say "Just because swimmers have made this word popular doesn't mean they have the right to a monopoly!"

Answer (score 5):

Not an exact equivalent, but specifically for your example I'd simply use **"schedule."**  You want a verb, and this comes closest to "arrange in time."

> I will collocate the two meetings so that they start and finish at the same time
>
> I will schedule the two meetings so that they start and finish at the same time

Comment: You can also schedule them so they *aren't* at the same time. By itself the word doesn't fit the requirement.

Answer (score 4):

[Coexist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coexist?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) (from Merriam-Webster):

> to exist together or at the same time

[Coincide](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coincide)

> to occupy the same place in space or time

Example:

My meetings *coincide* with each other.

Comment: *coincide* 2. To happen at the same time or during the same period. – [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coincide) Your example lends itself to the first definition, which includes time and/or space. *Since no one has to attend both, I've scheduled the meetings to coincide.*

Comment: Based off of the example given in the question, OP is looking for a *transitive* verb, not an intransitive verb.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the adjective **simultaneous** or adverb **simultaneously**

> **Simultaneous**: Happening, existing, or done at the same time.

You may set up simultaneous meetings

Or

You may set up meetings simultaneously

Comment: The latter phrasing, "set up meetings simultaneously", actually applies the adverb *simultaneously* to the verb phrase *set up*. This suggests you'll do the work of setting up one meeting at the same time you'll do the same work for the other meeting; the two meetings could still occur at different times. More accurate would be "set up meetings *to occur* simultaneously".

Comment: @talmu, I got your point. Agreed. Adverb leads to ambiguity.

Comment: OP asks for a verb.

Answer (score 2):

*I will **parallelise** the two meetings*

or more simply :

*I will run the two meetings **in parallel**.*

An similar example example, quoting Wikipedia:

> A large meeting will usually be called a conference, while a smaller is termed a workshop. They might be single track or multiple track, where the former has only one session at a time, **while a multiple track meeting has several parallel sessions** with speakers in separate rooms speaking at the same time.
>   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_conference

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's made it into any dictionaries yet, but I hear **"*coschedule*"** at conferences and around the office fairly frequently.

I believe a typical English speaker would understand this just fine, although if you're in an extremely-formal *written* context, you might pick another expression, since this word is still emerging in terms of recognition in general use.

---

Note however that it's not a *new* term; there's a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coscheduling) that describes its usage in the context of computing (apparently dating back to 1982) that fits what you want just fine:

> Coscheduling is the principle for concurrent systems of scheduling related processes to run... in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Collocate is still the word you want. No need to replace it. The word "location" is not restricted to spatial locations but can be temporal as well. A location in time is just as much a location as a location in space. In fact, strictly speaking, all locations are spatiotemporal.

Comment: This would introduce the potential for confusion.  Are the meetings now in the same location?  Are they sharing the meeting space?  Are the two meetings combined into one meeting?

Comment: "temporally collocate"

Comment: @ColinZwanziger - There's a single word for that, the second definition of which IMO is the colloquial (since *spatiotemporal* is not a colloquial concept) : [coincide](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403222/equivalent-of-collocate-but-for-time-rather-than-space#comment957970_403225)

Comment: @thomj1332 that possibility for confusion would seem to be inherent in the question and thus all possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

**coterminous**

having the same boundaries or extent in space, *time*, or meaning.
[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coterminous)

Comment: Based off of his example, OP is looking for a verb or verb-phrase. This answer would be correct if the word were the adjective "collocated".

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Steve Lovell suggestion, ***coordinate*** would be a correct word. Citing Cambridge Online Dictionary:

> **coordinate:** to make various, separate things work together

You want those meetings to "work together" at the same time and unlike other answers, ***coordinating meetings*** is already a common phrase, so you don't risk awkward phrasing or misunderstandings, when using this word.